# not able to click on button added using custom html in elementor

Tags: javascript, wordpress, elementor

I have a question.
I have added a button in elementor like this
`<button onclick="myFunction(1)" id="myBtn1">See More</button>`

and added the myFunction(1) using a code snippet. This function works when I am logged in as admin. But when I am logged out,it's not working and the console shows the button as

`<button id="myBtn1">See More</button>`

Does anyone know how to fix this?
How do I make `onclick` function to show up when I'm logged out?

Answer (score 0):

The issue you are encountering might be related to how WordPress handles user privileges and access to certain JavaScript code. When you're logged in as an admin, you might have more privileges, and some scripts are enqueued or executed differently for logged-in users or you could have a problem with your caching plugin, make sure to disable it while developing something.

Comment: I tried deactivating all plugins and even removed cache but it doesnt work. Also I looked if I had any user privilege plugin and I dont.